# Can't get the value from an object properly. (TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, filter

I am trying to make a search box which filters some data (object) when users put search term and display the result.

This is the code.

```
state = {
    names: customerData.name, 
    searchTerm: ''
};

 editSearchTerm = (e) => {
        this.setState({searchTerm: e.target.value})
    }

 dynamicSearch = () => {
        return this.state.names.filter(name => 
           name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()))
    }
```

This is the data.

```
customerData = [
   {
    "index" = 0,
    "age" = 20,
    "name" = "A"
   },
   {
    "index" = 1,
    "age" = 30,
    "name" = "B"
   }
]
```

when I execute the code it returns an error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined".

Looks like

```
names: customerData.name
```

is not the right way of getting the value of the data. What is the correct way to get the value from it?

Comment: How is `customerData.name` getting set? Basically, you can't access `this.state.names` until `customerData.name` has data, or you can give it a default value until it does (e.g., `names: []`, then when you get `customerData`... `customerData = ...; this.setState({ names: customerData.name });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the state, give an empty array `[]` to names.

```
state = {
    names: [],
    searchTerm: ''
};
```

And change the `names` state when you get the `customData`. Don't forget to check if `customData.names` is a valid array. Please check if `customData.names` is returning array.

```
if (customData.names) {
    this.setState({
        names: customData.names
    })
}
```